# What are static C# class variables for in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, static, static-members

I know what static class variables do in a C++ class, what I'm not very clear about is the life-cycle of static class variables in a C# class used for an ASP.NET web app. Here's a code example:

```
namespace MyWebApp
{
    public static class MyFunctions
    {
        private static string _cachedID;

        public static string getID(string strValue)
        {
            if(_cachedID == null)
                _cachedID = strValue;

            return _cachedID;
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone explain it in plain English for me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've read somewhere.

A static variable/field comes into existence before execution of the static *constructor* for its containing type, and ceases to exist when the associated application domain ceases to exists.

Comment: Thanks. So, say, if my web app is posted at www.mydomain.com URL and the first user logs in to it via a web browser. The cachedID var will be set. But then if a totally different user from another computer logs in to the same URL the cachedID will be already set to that first value. Is that what you're saying?

Comment: @ahmd0, yes. There is exactly one instance of the static member for whole AppDomain.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, there's a difference between the singleton pattern (in which there's is only one instance possible assigned to a static field for the lifetime of the AppDomain) and a static field in general in which you could assign as many instances as you want during the lifetime of the AppDomain.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov, hmmm... I'm not exactly sure how one would phrase the fact that static field allocated exactly ones and shared in whole AppDomain. My attempt was "instance of the static member" which as I can see now may be read as reference to singleton pattern instead.

Comment: `static field allocated exactly ones and shared in whole AppDomain` -> that's perfect like this. There is no more confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are asking this question in the context of a multithreaded ASP.NET application, you should be extremely careful. Checkout the following scenario:

2 users Bob and Alice call the `getID` method at exactly the same time passing different arguments. Bob passes `Foo` and Alice passes `Bar`. Since this is the first call, the `_cachedID` variable is not yet initialized so both enter the `if` condition, Bob with a slight delay. So Alice sets `the _cachedID` static variable to `Bar` and a microsecond after, `Bob` sets it to `Foo`. Now the code continues and the function returns `Foo` for both users. Bob of course is happy because that's what he wanted, but Alice wanted `Bar`.

For example if you wanted to perform a one time initialization in a multithreaded environment you might consider using the thread safe version of the [Singleton Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx).

The moral of this is that you should be extremely careful when dealing with shared/static data in an ASP.NET application. If you need to use it you need to properly synchronize the access to it or very bad things could happen. And they usually happen in production when your application is concurrently accessed by multiple users. On your local PC everything will work fine.

And back to your original question about the lifetime of a static fields: it is tied to the lifetime of the application domain.

Comment: Thanks, Darin. It explains it pretty well. I'll keep this in mind. One question on the side though -- how does the IIS server remember that variable when we're talking about web browsers accessing my web app?

Comment: IIS doesn't remember anything. It is the application domain in which your ASP.NET application executes that stores it in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Classes which you can't and dont have to make an object of but you can only acces it from a static context.

you would use your example like this:

```
MyFunctions.getID("bla");
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the link. What I'm not clear is the life-cycle of those static variables in the ASP.NET environment?